# ActionSheetStringPicker header not showing properly with UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem

I found a header design issue in ActionSheetStringPicker with UIBarButtonItem. How to solve this?

Screenshot:

[image]

Code:

```
func openFilter(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    let arr:NSArray = sortingArray as NSArray
    ActionSheetStringPicker.show(withTitle: "Filter Data", rows: arr as [AnyObject], initialSelection: filterPosition, doneBlock: {
        picker, value, index in
        self.filterPosition = value
        self.selectedPos = -1
        self.filterData()
        self.tableViewMain.setContentOffset(.zero, animated:true)
    }, cancel: { ActionStringCancelBlock in return }, origin: sender)
}
```

Comment: What is `ActionSheetStringPicker`? If it is a library you are using, you should probably contact the author of that.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because SO is not a place to submit bug reports for 3rd party libraries. Please submit this on the 3rd party library's website.